# ComboBox items with a binded value

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

In my WPF page I would like to create a `ComboBox` with first item empty and the second one binded with a property value, so I did:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="grdTmplBit" ColumnWidth="*" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" CanUserSortColumns="true" Margin="4,3,2,7" MaxHeight="930" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="FullRow" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ObjectsTree, Path=SelectedItem.InfosView, IsAsync=True}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>                            
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="110" Header="COMM" Visibility="Visibile">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox Width="90" SelectedValue="{Binding Comm.UnitName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{StaticResource workModeStyle}" SelectedValuePath="Content">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="" />
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Comm.UnitName}" />
                    </ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```

The property `UnitName` is a `string`. Please consider that the `ComboBox` is inside a `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Basically the second item is always empty and if I change the `ComboBox` with a `TextBox` the value are shown correctly. Any help?

Comment: Seeing a `ComboBox` without its `ItemsSource` property not being bound is strange to say the least.

Comment: There is no ItemSource as the elements should be defined directly in the xaml with ComboBoxItem

Comment: I think you should clarify your question, you want the user to select either `UnitName` or `null` ?

Comment: Both, he can choose between UnitName (e.g. "Foobar") or null. If I put directly "Foobar" as value of Content property, it works

Comment: "Please consider that the combobox is inside a DataGridTemplateColumn. " - please consider making a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that you bind the `SelectedValue` to `Comm.UnitName` and you also bind the second `ComboBoxItem` content to this property. This means the `ComboBox` will act in one of these ways:

- (Initial selected value is from `Comm.UnitName`) > The selected line shows this item> You select the empty item > The `Comm.UnitName` will get set to the empty `string` > Result: Both `ComboBoxItem`s are empty (one is set as empty, the other is synchronized with `Comm.UnitName`, which is empty now, too)
- (Initial selected value is the first item, empty) > The selected line shows this item > The `Comm.UnitName` will get set to the empty `string` > Result: The same as above.

In order to solve this issue, you could consider one of these options:

- Create a dedicated property for the `SelectedValue`, so the `Comm.UnitName` does not get overwritten.
- Create a dedicated property for the value in the `ComboBoxItem`.
- Use a `OneTime` mode binding to only synchronize the initial value (this does not work for all cases, especially not if you save the empty value in `Comm.UnitName`, same issue).

  ```
  <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Comm.UnitName, Mode=OneTime}" />
  ```